How can I make one process handle the queue operations and other one execute the query's in the queue
In this code below (server), I need to be able to receive the client's query's, insert them in the FCFS queue and, at the same time, I need those query's to be executed by the server.
I know the code below doesn't do what I need, and I'm out of the ideas how to do so. I can't use semaphores, multi-threading etc.. I'm only allowed to use fork's and pipe's, if necessary.
I'm aware that I need to use pipe's between those two processes but I have no idea how.
SERVER.C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    char** queue = malloc(sizeof (char*) * 15);
    int queue_size = 0;

    if (mkfifo("fifo", 0666) == -1) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd_server = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
    
    Queue* fcfs_queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    newQueue(fcfs_queue);

    int pid_enqueue = fork();
    if (pid_enqueue == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (pid_enqueue == 0) { //read the input from the client
        while(1) {
            if (fcfs_queue->head != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", fcfs_queue->head->data);
                deQueue(fcfs_queue);
            }
        }
        _exit(0);
    } else {
        while(1) {
            char* toRead = malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
            ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd_server, toRead, sizeof(char) * 15);
            if (bytes_read > 0) {
                enQueue(fcfs_queue, toRead);
            }
        }
    }

    close(fd_server);



    return 0;
}   

CLIENT.C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    //argv[1] must have less that 16 characters

    int fd_server = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);
    if (fd_server == -1) {
        perror("server");
        return 1;
    }
    char* toWrite = strdup(argv[1]);
    strcpy(toWrite, argv[1]);
    ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd_server, toWrite, strlen(toWrite) + 1);
    printf("%d", bytes_written);
    close(fd_server);

    return 0;

}

QUEUE_MANAGER.C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char* data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int tamanho;
} Queue;

void newQueue(Queue* aux) {
    aux->head = NULL;
    aux->tail = NULL;
    aux->tamanho = 0;
}

void enQueue(Queue* fila, char* toInsert) {
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (!newNode) {
        perror("malloc");
        return;
    }
    newNode->data = strdup(toInsert); 
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (fila->tail != NULL) {
        fila->tail->next = newNode;
    }
    fila->tail = newNode;

    if (fila->head == NULL) {
        fila->head = newNode;
    }

    fila->tamanho++;
}


void deQueue(Queue* fila) {
    if (fila->head != NULL) {
        Node* temp = fila->head;
        fila->head = fila->head->next;
        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);
        if (fila->head == NULL) {
            fila->tail = NULL;
        }
        fila->tamanho--;
    }
}

I've already tried to make the server request the son process if he is available to handle a queue,
if so we would execute. I used two pipe's in this solution but it wasn't working.

Two pipes should be fine. Are you closing the correct sides of the pipe? Please edit your question and post your full code here. We would really like an MRE. For C, we would like a single .c file [with (e.g.) #include <stdio.h>]. But, no (e.g.) #include "myprogram.h" (For those, copy-and-paste in the .h contents.) For runtime errors, it should compile cleanly. We should be able to download, build, and run it on our local systems [if we so choose].

Thank you Craig, I've updated the code... The problem is, those two pipe's must be always open right? One to see if the son is available and the other one to send the query to execute?

Okay, I see a few issues with the code. It would help if you could edit your question and describe what you're trying to do (i.e. intent vs [your] implementation). So, something like: "I have a client that sends requests to the server. The server processes the requests and sends back results to the client." You've only got one pipe: it sends data from client to server (but no data goes in the reverse direction--that needs a second/different pipe).

Why does the server fork? Doing enqueue in the child uses child memory. Doing dequeue in the parent uses parent memory. After the fork, these are not the same, so the queue won't work. It would work if you were using threads. It would work if you used shared memory (e.g. shmget/shmat or mmap). So, I'd rewrite to not use fork. Maybe, in your problem statement, it would be clear why you wanted to fork to solve a specific issue of the problem.

The only work that the client has to do, is send requests to the server. From this point, the server must just execute the request from the client and nothing more. I want to use fork because that's a project for University, and we are not allowed to use shared memory, threads etc... Only pipe's and fork's. The solution that I'm thinking is to have two pipe's connected between the son and parent processes that share the requests to execute... I've already tried this but no sucess lol

Processes are typically generally gender neutral.  The child process is not called "son"; it's called "child".

You were very close ...

The server does not need to fork. This breaks the queue because the server's child writes to different memory than the server parent.
Because pipes can have "short read" or "short write", we can use fdopen to get a stream.
Then, we can use fputs and fgets instead of raw write/read
Your queue logic was okay (with some simplifications).
I've added a newline separater between commands.

The server needs two loops:

read commands from the pipe and enqueue them.
dequeue and process the command


Here is the modified server.c (I've merged in queue.c):
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char *data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct {
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    int tamanho;
} Queue;

void
newQueue(Queue *aux)
{
    aux->head = NULL;
    aux->tail = NULL;
    aux->tamanho = 0;
}

void
enQueue(Queue *fila, char *toInsert)
{
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if (!newNode) {
        perror("malloc");
        return;
    }

    newNode->data = strdup(toInsert);
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (fila->tail != NULL) {
        fila->tail->next = newNode;
    }
    fila->tail = newNode;

    if (fila->head == NULL)
        fila->head = newNode;

    fila->tamanho++;
}

void
deQueue(Queue *fila)
{
    Node *temp = fila->head;

    if (temp != NULL) {
        fila->head = temp->next;

        free(temp->data);
        free(temp);

        if (fila->tail == temp)
            fila->tail = NULL;

        fila->tamanho--;
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (mkfifo("fifo", 0666) == -1) {
        perror("mkfifo");
        return 1;
    }

    int fd_server = open("fifo", O_RDONLY);
    FILE *fi = fdopen(fd_server,"r");

    Queue *fcfs_queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    newQueue(fcfs_queue);

    char toRead[1000];

    while (1) {
        char *cp = fgets(toRead,sizeof(toRead),fi);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // strip newline
        toRead[strcspn(toRead,"\n")] = 0;

        enQueue(fcfs_queue,toRead);
    }

    fclose(fi);

    while (1) {
        Node *cur = fcfs_queue->head;
        if (cur == NULL)
            break;

        printf("%s\n", cur->data);
        deQueue(fcfs_queue);
    }

    return 0;
}


Here is the modified client.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // argv[1] must have less that 16 characters

    // skip over program name
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    int fd_server = open("fifo", O_WRONLY);

    if (fd_server == -1) {
        perror("server");
        return 1;
    }

// NOTE: strdup not needed
#if 0
    char *toWrite = strdup(argv[1]);
    strcpy(toWrite, argv[1]);
#else
    char *toWrite;
#endif

#if 1
    FILE *fo = fdopen(fd_server,"w");
#endif

#if 0
    ssize_t bytes_written = write(fd_server, toWrite, strlen(toWrite) + 1);
    printf("%d", bytes_written);
    close(fd_server);
#else
    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        toWrite = *argv;
        fputs(toWrite,fo);
        fputc('\n',fo);
    }
    fclose(fo);
#endif

    return 0;

}


In the code above, I've used cpp conditionals to denote old vs. new code:
#if 0
// old code
#else
// new code
#endif

#if 1
// new code
#endif

Note: this can be cleaned up by running the file through unifdef -k

Here is the client command:
./client quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Here is the server output:
quick
brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy
dog

